# Importing Blob images from a data base

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, image

So, i have to import images from my database and I have tried all the possible options, the images are uploaded by the user so I dont control the extension of the file. Oh yes and images have to appears in a list, one image for each article, so my code is in a boucle. And well I think is a database config problem or maybe the way I upload the image because its been 3 hours and I cant solve this!

Here is the Upload code:

```
$imageName = addslashes($_FILES['imagen1']['name']);
$imageTempName =  $_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
$imageBlob = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']) );
$imageType=pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$permit=array("jpg", "tif", "gif", "png", "raw", "jpeg", "bmp");

$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lacajota', 'root', '', $pdo_options);

$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO imagenes(userID, articID, name, image)
       VALUES(:userID, :articID, :name, :image)');
$req->execute(array(

            'userID'=> $_SESSION['userID'],
            'articID'=> $LastArtLast['ID'],
            'name'=> $imageName,
            'image'=> $imageBlob
            ));
```

I have skip some no important lines

And here is the code to extract the image:

> STEP 1 SIMPLE LINK TO IMAGE (this is in a boucle)

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo  $userInfoLastART1['ID'];?>" class="imageArtList">
```

> AND STEP 2 MAKING getImage.php MY IMAGE

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];


 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("imagenes");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE articID=$id";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

mysql_close($link);

header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  echo $row['image'];
```

So this is all I repeat this is not a repeated question!

Thank you very much have a nice day!

Comment: I removed  (not solved yet) from your title. Not seeing an accepted answer, makes it that; unsolved. So wait for a solution.

Comment: (a) problem here is, you're using PDO and mysql_, you can't mix those different APIs together.

Comment: You mean when I insert the image in the db? the first code block?

Comment: Because the Bloob is registed in my database

Comment: @Boris Why are you doing `mysql_select_db("imagenes")`? Isn't "imagenes" the table name?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: No the db base name is lacajota

Comment: @Boris So remove that line in your code

Comment: @Fred-ii- should I edit or remove it?

Comment: So what is your problem you haven't mentioned any errors?

Comment: @Boris Edit it. Change it to select the right db.

Comment: @Dagon bucle sorry

Comment: @MikeT the error is that the image is not here

Comment: @Midas I did it and nothing changes

Comment: @Boris Well, an error != the same as behaviour. Try fixing the mentioned points, and call `mysql_error()` after `mysql_query()` to see if it produces any errors.

Comment: well that's not English either

Comment: @Midas I did it and I have no error

Comment: @Boris Did you echo it? `echo mysql_error()`

Comment: @Midas yep and is not working

Comment: @Midas should I upload an image to show you? the browser try to show the image

Comment: @Midas https://i.imgsafe.org/8acac23a64.png

Comment: @Fred-ii- https://i.imgsafe.org/8acac23a64.png

Answer (score 1):

## File Contents of an Image must be handled as binary, and NOT modified.

I assume your `addslashes()` function is an attempt to escape special characters and prevent sql injection. Unfortunately, that is almost certain to be screwing up your image blob (**B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject).

This line, is likely altering the binary.

```
$imageBlob = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']) );
```

Additionally, your PDO::Execute() call does not specify the proper type for binary data for the BLOB.

#### Important Notes

- If you are properly using PDO, PDO will handle this for you.

  - What you're currently doing should be sufficient, but you need to tell PDO to handle the image as binary.
  - You'd likely find your code to be easier to manage if you also used it for `getImage.php`.

## Solution

```
$imageName      = addslashes($_FILES['imagen1']['name']);
$imageTempName  = $_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
//$imageBlob        = file_get_contents( imageTempName );
$imageBlob      = fopen($imageTempName , 'rb');

$imageType=pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$permit=array("jpg", "tif", "gif", "png", "raw", "jpeg", "bmp");

$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lacajota', 'root', '', $pdo_options);

$req = $bdd->prepare('
    INSERT INTO imagenes
        (userID, articID, name, image)
    VALUES
        (:userID, :articID, :name, :image)'
);

$req->bindParam(':userID', $_SESSION['userID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam(':articID', $LastArtLast['ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$req->bindParam(':name', $imageName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindParam(':image', $imageBlob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$req->execute();
```

Comment: Nice find, I missed thisone

Comment: I have uploaded my code let me run it

Comment: Thank you for your big and interesting answer but no... is not working

Comment: Then the way you are handling the image-file itself is not binary. 
Have you tried accessing the local-file `$_FILES['imagen1']['tmp_name']` to make sure the image is good at that stage?

Comment: After you've checked that, try writing the `$row['image'];` to the content of a local-file, and checking that.

Comment: Also, it could be that php is configured such that `file_get_contents()` is not in binary mode, so try my adjustment `$imageBlob = fopen($imageTempName , 'rb');`.

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

instead of

```
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
```

Comment: Maybe but that dosent solve the probleme Thankyou

Comment: `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");` is valid http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php - Only thing, the `type` should be uppercase T. There "might" be an issue, but kind of doubt it though.